# Laravel reducing queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I use Laravel Eloquent and I have this code:

```
<?php
$bulk = Bulk::where('id', 'bulkid1');
echo $bulk->info;
foreach($bulk->models as $model) {
  echo $model->info;
  $lastreport = $model->reports()->getQuery()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
  echo $lastreport->message;
}    
?>
```

What I want to achieve is that the `$lastreport` is preloaded. In this piece of code, the query will be executed too many times (every bulk has 1000 models, resulting in 1000 subqueries).
While in plain sql I could just do:

```
SELECT * FROM bulk
LEFT JOIN models ON bulk.id = models.bulk_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
   FROM
     reports
   GROUP BY
     model_id )
lastreport ON models.id = lastreport.model_id
WHERE bulk.id = 'bulkid1'
```

Database pseudocode:

```
TABLE bulks
 id, info

TABLE models
id, bulk_id, info

TABLE reports
id, model_id, message
```

Comment: What does your database look like?

Comment: You mean the relations? 1 bulk has * models and every model has * reports. I added some pseudocode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [N+1 selects problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-object-relational-mapping) The laravel solution for this problem is [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

In your case you'd do:

```
<?php
$bulk = Bulk::with(['models', 'models.reports' => function ($query) { 
      return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');           
   } 
])->where('id', 'bulkid1')->first();
echo $bulk->info;
foreach($bulk->models as $model) {
  echo $model->info;
  $lastreport = $model->reports->first();
  echo $lastreport->message;
}
```

This should ensure that (a) all models are loaded with only 1 additional query and (b) all model reports are loaded with another additional query. The downside with this is that there are more data being loaded than necessary because of the `orderBy` clause which can't really be represented as a query time condition.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. This is exactly what i'm looking for!